# Is there a GUI for setting access to Extn drives for other users?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hdd, ubuntu-studio

Otherwise I suppose I should be taking the time to learn [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/694111/help-allow-another-user-to-access-partitioned-drives-on-ubuntu-15) but I just want a GUI.

Btw, in case it makes a difference, I'm using Ubuntu-Studio 16.04

Comment: You will need to explain what you are trying to do, what the expected result is and what happens instead. Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/779499/edit) your question and add the information.

Comment: Have you looked at the application `Disks`? it is preinstalled and may be what you need.

Comment: Do you just want to share a drive?

Comment: Mark K, unfortunately Disks didn't help me. I went to the other user's account and used it. Those drives are mounted already, but when I attempt to open them a pop up window asks me what do I want to use to open it. Instead of just using File Browser. And if I point to File Browser it just refreshes the page but won't do anything.

Christopher A-B, yes. That's all I want to do. Sure it would be nice if it were to be shared by default every time the user logs in. So there wouldn't be the need to do something cumbersome every time this is needed.
Btw, making the user an Admin didn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

In the menu, go to `System` > `Users and Groups`, and there, select the user, click on `"advanced settings"` button, and in the `"User Privileges"` tab, mark the option `"Access External Storage Devices Automatically"`.  That's all.

Comment: You could also try this, but this is no GUI: http://askubuntu.com/questions/742487/sharing-an-external-hard-drive-between-users